# selecting distinct values where based on multiple arguments

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I hope i word this out in a way that makes sense;

I'm trying to do a basic select statement for a list of companyIDs. The arguments in questions are options regarding invoices. We have multiple invoice types and they can either be set to be sent by E-mail or be printed. They can be mixed as in some e-mail, some printed, some have nothing selected. There's a total of 9 unique invoice types that i need to check for each company ID.

I'm trying to select distinct company IDs(cmp_id) where the print AND e-mail options are all N or NULL for every single invoicetype. Both options have to be off for both print and e-mail for all invoice types ( In the table i'm selecting from, there's 9 records for the same companyID for each invoicetype)

Some examples ( I'm only using 3 invoice types for the example):

```
Cmp_id   invoiceType     print e-mail
company1    credit         Y       N    
company1    supplemental   Y       N
company1    misc           Y       Y
company2    supplemental   N       N
company2    misc           N       N
```

The results should be a single column for cmp_id; In the example it would only be company2.

Comment: you have 9 invoice types ... but always have `print` and `email`?

Comment: @samalkobi in your sample data you have 3 invoice types: credit, supplemental, and misc. are these the only types or like you said there are 9?

Comment: There are actually 9 in total but i figured it would be simpler to only use 3 for this example to keep it cleaner.

Comment: In your sample company2 only have 2 rows and still is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just perfrom a coditional `COUNT` to check how many `'Y'` you have.

Im assuming `print` and `e-mail` only have 3 states, `Y`, `N` or `NULL`

```
 SELECT Cmp_id   
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY Cmp_id   
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN print = 'Y' or e-mail = 'Y' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

So if count is 0 mean all values are `NULL` or `N`

**[Working DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/73ebb/3)**

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: You can update the sqlFiddle in my DEMO to provide a more complete sample data.

Comment: Sorry about that; I just re-ran it with COUNT(InvoiceType) and confirmed they are all showing 9, which is correct. I ran a separate query to check the status on the CompanyIDs returned and they are all N or NULL. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cmp_ID from dbo.table where  (Print = 'N') AND (E-Mail = 'N') OR
  (Print IS NULL) AND (E-Mail IS NULL)
```

Comment: This work for one row, but OP want to make sure all rows have `N` or `NULL`

Comment: But would not catch NULL and N or vice versa and could probably do with some parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cmp_ID 
FROM dbo.table 
WHERE 
COALESCE([Print], 'N') = 'N' 
AND
COALESCE([E-Mail], 'N') = 'N'
```

Use coalesce to catch the NULLs and Ns.

Comment: This work for one row, but OP want to make sure all company rows have `N` or `NULL`

Comment: This wont work. If you change third row to `('company1', 'misc', 'N', 'N'),` you will get `company1` but not all `company1` are `N` or `NULL`. And

Comment: You can watch this demo [**HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/73ebb/3). I have to use postgres because sql server was broken but result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:

each `[Cmp_ID]` has n rows in the table where n is the number of `[invoiceTypes]`

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ([Cmp_id] VARCHAR(20),   [invoiceType] VARCHAR(20),  [print] VARCHAR(20),  [e-mail] VARCHAR(20), )

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
('company1','credit','Y','N'),
('company1','supplemental','Y','N'),
('company1','misc','Y','Y'),
('company2','credit','N','N'),
('company2','supplemental','N','N'),
('company2','misc','N','N')
```

Query using Common table Expression, GROUP BY and HAVING:

We assign the value 1 for every row that has `[Print]`, and `[e-mail]` as `NULL` or `'N'`. Then we only retrieve the `[Cmp_id]` of the company that has all its invoiceType with `[Print]`, and `[e-mail]` as `NULL` or `'N'`.

```
;WITH CTE AS ( SELECT [Cmp_id], 
                 [NoneSelected] = CASE WHEN ISNULL([print],'N') = 'N' AND ISNULL([e-mail],'N') ='N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             FROM #temp )
SELECT Cmp_id 
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY Cmp_id 
HAVING SUM(NoneSelected) = 3 --<-- change this to 9 for 9 invoice types
```

Results:

[image]

Try using Temp tables in response to the comment "We're on compatibility 80, i've tried using CTEs before but they didn't work :S Thanks forthe input though.":

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp2') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #temp2;

       SELECT [Cmp_id], 
                [NoneSelected] = CASE WHEN ISNULL([print],'N') = 'N' AND ISNULL([e-mail],'N') ='N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END INTO #temp2
           FROM #temp  

    SELECT Cmp_id 
    FROM #temp2 
    GROUP BY Cmp_id 
    HAVING SUM(NoneSelected) = 3 --<-- change this to 9 for 9 invoice types
```

Comment: We're on compatibility 80, i've tried using CTEs before but they didn't work :S Thanks forthe input though.

Comment: @samalkobi you can use temp tables see my addition to the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.Cmp_id, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.table T1
WHERE 
COALESCE([Print], 'N') = 'N' 
AND
COALESCE([E-Mail], 'N') = 'N' 
GROUP BY T1.Cmp_id
HAVING COUNT(T1.Cmp_id) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.table WHERE Cmp_id = T1.Comp_Id)
```

Count where both options are either NULL or N and that count = the count of Cmp_Ids in the table.